# PHP date into mySQL database isn't working as planned

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

So I've been trying to solve this one on my own for a few hours and it's driving me crazy.

I'm just trying to put a date into a mySQL database, the code looks like this:

```
$timeStarted = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO deviceStats (currTime, ...) VALUES ($timeStarted, ...)";
mysql_query($sqlquery);
echo $timeStarted;
```

My ajax return is telling me that $timeStarted is in the propper format, it's giving the right time, but if I have this one variable in my query, it won't run. the currTime field in the DB is set to datetime, so it should work.

Comment: why on earth did my question get downranked?

Comment: There are some idiots around, don't worry. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that date strings in MySQL are exactly that, *strings* and as such must either be quoted (single quotes) or preferably, passed as parameters.

Using PDO, this would be quite simple

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO `deviceStats` (`currTime`, ...) VALUES (?, ...)');
$ts = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $ts);
$stmt->execute();
echo $ts;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use NOW()?

```
$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO deviceStats (currTime, ...) VALUES (NOW(), ...);
```

Comment: I need to echo that NOW(), so I need something saved to a php variable. If I can echo NOW() then that's golden!

Comment: Run this query `select NOW()` (but running this after your first query will make the value slightly off). Or you can go `mysql_last_insert_id();` and re-select the record to get the value of now.

Comment: can you output what the sql looks like exactly so that we can see what the complete statement looks like?

Comment: try wrapping the variable in a single quote.

$sqlquery = "INSERT INTO deviceStats (currTime, ...) VALUES ('$timeStarted', ...)";

Comment: you called it, single quotes. I owe you a beer.